# Insert ")" to complete Expression error while new HashMap as parameter

Tags: java, hashmap

I get the error: `Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression` when I am trying to do this:

```
public interface IConectorT extends Library {
HashMap<String, String> xx= new HashMap<>();
IConectorT INSTANCE = (IConectorT) Native.loadLibrary("Eloqua API", IConectorT.class, new 
HashMap{{
      put("DeleteCustomObjectRecord", "DeleteCustomObjectRecord@8");
      }});
}
```

Why is that? I thought its because it isnt JRE 1.7 but changing to that didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HashMap constructor missing the parenthesis

```
new HashMap{{
```

should be

```
 new HashMap(){{
```

Comment: Sometimes my head compiler just misses really obvious stuff like this due to poor formatting. Your head compiler is clearly superior! +1